# Release and Retain in No-ARC case in a block

Tags: objective-c, reference-counting

I am not sure if I fully understand how to use release and retain.
For example:
In this case

```
@interface MyClass :NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObj* myObj;
@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myObj = _myObj;

- (void)aFunction
{
    void(^myBlock)(void) =
    ^{
        MyObj* aLocalObj = [[MyObj alloc] init];
        [self setMyObj:aLocalObj];

        [aLocalObj release];// Question here: I wonder if we need to relesae block local variable aLocalString in No-ARC case?

    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{myBlock();});
}

@end
```

I wonder if we need to release "aLocalObj" in the block?

In my mind, [aLocalObj release] is not needed, since in the [self setMyObj:aLocalObj]; it passes the memory to myObj property. And the myObj property takes over the allocated memory, And _myObj will have ref count 1 ?

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to call release. If you call `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain`, you own the object and you must call `release` - unless you specifically pass the ownership off to someone else (which isn't too common).

The use of a block here isn't relevant.

Here's the full reference count:

1. You call `alloc/init` - reference count is 1.
2. You call `setMyObj:` - reference count is 2 (since the property is retained).
3. You call `aLocalObj release` - reference count is 1.
4. In `dealloc` you call `_myObj release` - reference count is 0.

BTW - this is why you should be using ARC. No need to worry about any of these details.

Comment: In this case I wonder if [self setMyObj:aLocalObj]; means pass the ownership off to myObj property ?

Comment: No, it does not pass off ownership. It's additional ownership.

Comment: Could you please make an example, in which case it means passing owner ship to someone else?

Comment: There's no point since it's so rare you would ever do that. Follow the simple rules of ownership - you create it, you release it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to release the object, because setting a retained property increases the retain counter.

Workflow:

```
// -> retainCount = 0  
[[MyObj alloc] init];      // -> retainCount = 1
[self setMyObj:aLocalObj]; // -> retainCount = 2
[aLocalObj release];       // -> retainCount = 1
```

setting the property to `nil` will set the counter to zero and deallocate the object